# NoScript has autoupdate on in TBB 3.6.6

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, add-on

NoScript has autoupdate on in TBB 3.6.6. So my NoScript has updated at least two times.

Is the autoupdate on a bug? If yes, what should I do? Reinstall TBB 3.6.6 and switch off the autoupdate? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in obsolete software

Comment: As @Sebastian said, TBB 3.6.6 is outdated. Current version is at https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en and I will close this question.